# Is there any way to access arguments of handler method in a NestJS guard?

Tags: annotations, nestjs, decorator

I want to implement a smart guard in NestJS which can protect method execution based on decisions declared in a special method annotation.

For example the use-case is:

normal users can change only their own user information

Admin can change any user information

I want to specify decisions by declarative way: using annotations. I've almost completed the implementation, this requirement can be declared this way:

```
@Put('user')
@UseGuards(HttpBasicAuthGuard, DecisionGuard)
@DecisionExpr(new Decisions(Op.OR, [
  new RootDecision(Role.ADMIN),
  new CurrentUserDecision({ sourceParamId: 'user', func: (user: User) => user.id}),
]))
updateUser(@ParamId('user') @Body() u: User, @ParamId('etc') etc): any {
  // call user service and update user in model
}
```

- Declared decisions are stored into metadata of handler method by
  '@DecisionExpr'.
- Parameter indexes are collected by '@ParamId' and also stored into
  metadata of handler method.
- Decisions are evaluated by DecisionGuard which can access current
  user and authorities from Request (via ExecutionContext), it can also
  access easily decisions and identified parameter indexes from
  metadata.

The only problem how can I access arguments of handler method from DecisionGuard. Arguments of handler method contain data which can be compared to the current user and make a decision for DecisionGuard.

Is it possible, at all?

The only way I found was to implement a method decorator and call a custom method by changing PropertyDescriptor.value (3rd argument of method decorator):

```
export const DecisionExpr = (data: Decision): MethodDecorator => {
    ...
    const childFunction = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = (...args: any[]) => {
      console.log('DecisionExpr child function - args:', args);
      // call original method
      return childFunction.apply(this, args);
    };
}
```

But the problem with this solution is that a custom method is only called AFTER guards.

My last chance is moving this protection from DecisionGuard into the custom method of DecisionExpr method decorator - but I don't like it. I don't want to introduce a new pattern for method protection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I will try this solution to fulfill my requirements:
https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authorization#integrating-casl